# Distribution of Stopped Brownian motion at hitting time of another Brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Suppose $B_t$ and $W_t$ are two independent Brownian motions and $\tau$ is the first hitting time of $B_t$ to some $a >0$. Compute the distribution of $W_{\tau}$.

We can try the characteristic function method. Consider $E[e^{iu W_{\tau}}] = E[E[e^{iuW_{\tau}}|F_{B}]]$. Now we would like to use the Independence Lemma to get that this is $E[E[e^{iuW_t}]|_{\tau=t}] = E[e^{\frac{-tu^2}{2}} |_{\tau=t}] = E[e^{\frac{-\tau u^2}{2}}] = e^{-|u|a}$ so that $W_{\tau}$ has the same characteristic function as the Cauchy distribution and the problem would be solved. But this is not quite the Independence Lemma.

The only Independence Lemma that I know says that $E[f(X,Y)|F_Z] = E[f(x,Y)]|_{X=x}$ when $Y$ is independent of $F_Z$ and $X$ is measurable wrt $F_Z$ and $f$ is a Borel function. Does anyone know if there is some other more complicated Independence Lemma that would yield the above computation?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your computation is valid. Probably the easiest way to show it is to note that, for every $t$,
$$
E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_\tau}\mid\tau=t)=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_t}\mid\tau=t)=E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_t}),
$$
where the second identity holds thanks to the independence of $W_t$ and $\tau$. One knows that, for every $t$, $E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_t})=\mathrm e^{-u^2t/2}$, hence
$$
E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_\tau}\mid\tau)=\mathrm e^{-u^2\tau/2},
$$
which implies that
$$
E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm iuW_\tau})=E(\mathrm e^{-u^2\tau/2}),
$$
and you are done since you are able to compute the RHS.

Comment: This is great. Thanks!